# VS Code: HTML file not pulling functions from attached javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Doing some basic practice/testing for a project I'm working on and can't get my html file to access the functions written in the attached javascript file. I feel like there's something super basic that I'm missing but I can't put my finger on it.

I pulled the basic button from here: [Creating an ON/OFF button with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089593/creating-an-on-off-button-with-javascript)
And I tried the solutions here: [HTML file not pulling information from javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479073/html-file-not-pulling-information-from-javascript-file)

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head> 
<body>
    <input type="button" value="X" id="turn" onclick="turn();">
</body>
</html>
```

My js:

```
function turn(){
    currentvalue = document.getElementById('turn').value;
    if(currentvalue == "X"){
        document.getElementById("turn").value="O";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("turn").value="X";
    }
}
```

The function itself works when embedded in a script tag within `<body>` but not when pulled from the attached javascript file. What am I missing?

Comment: Your code is running before the DOM loads. Either put the call to the script before the `</body>` [or use defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), or `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);`.

Comment: @Andy but the function likely doesn't run until after the document is loaded, since it is triggered by user click, so `document` should have been ready by then.

Comment: @Andy Tried all three of these and sadly did not work. Tried putting the script right above ```<body>```, at the top inside it, and at the bottom inside it. Then tried using defer in the script tag, and also added ```window.addEventListener... etc``` in the javascript and still nothing.

Comment: Not an answer to your question by why hit the DOM 3 times? it can just be `function turn() {
  let myTurn = document.getElementById('turn');
  myTurn.value =  myTurn.value == "X" ? "O" : "X";
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function turn(){
    currentvalue = document.getElementById('turn').value;
    if(currentvalue == "X"){
        document.getElementById("turn").value="O";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("turn").value="X";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head> 
<body>
    <input type="button" value="X" id="turn" onclick="turn();">
</body>
</html>
```

You need to add defer atrribute.

Comment: This fixed it! I tried this before but accidentally left ```window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);``` in my javascript at the same time and that was somehow causing an issue. Copied/pasted yours exactly (without that extra addition) and it somehow worked. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Your welcome. Defer makes it download js but wait to HTML parsing complete. Then parse js file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<script>` tag in body.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="X" id="turn" onclick="turn();" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For summary: Modern approach to old approach

- You can use `module` which are `defer`ed by default  `<script type="module" src="/app.js"></script>`
- You can use `defer` to make sure your js is executed after page has load i.e `<script src=app.js" defer></script>`
- You can put your `<script>` tag before `</body>` body tag closing

For more details, you can look at this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup).

Comment: Unfortunately tried this as well, and still nothing :(

Comment: Above works on my machine.

Comment: After edit: Tried module originally and sadly that didn't work either. Neither did defer, nor changing the position of my `<script>` tag.

Comment: You can use [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/eugercek/mbowvtn6)  to continue studying. I edited the answer again it seemed like you didn't have `<html>` tag open maybe it's the reason of bug.

Comment: Looks like the issue was that I accidentally left the ```window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);``` line in my javascript while also trying this method, and that was causing an issue. Removing it and adding ```defer``` into my ```<script>``` tag somehow fixed it . Thanks!